# How to check cronjob is working for laravel app in digital ocean server?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, cron

This is scheduling code in laravel.

Console .php

```
$schedule->command('mail:customer')->dailyAt('9:00 am'); 
$schedule->command('renew:booking')->dailyAt('9:00 am');
```

And I 'd like to run this on an Ubuntu server. I am just using crontab for email sending in laravel application. For this, I had used

```
* * * * * * php /var/www_testing/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

This command in digital ocean server. But I am not sure if this is working or not. So I just need to check this is working. Is there exact and fast way for testing?

Comment: It sorta looks like you have a syntax error on your `crontab`, should `1>>` just be `>>`? Also, you have 6 `*`, I'm not an expert for CRON, but it looks like you should only have 5: `* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` (although 6 may be ok as an optional one; not sure though)

Comment: yeah it should only have 5 * 6th one is for command in this I guess its php

Answer (score 1):

yes use facility of logs provided by laravel.

you can put something like this in your `Job` or `Command` whatever you have used.

```
public function handle()
{
  Log::info('Cron Job Started');
     // your logic 
  Log::info('Cron Job Ended');
}
```

This will put a log into `Laravel.log` file and if the cron is running perfectly you will get the log here..

Also you have syntax error here try this.

```
* * * * * php /var/www_testing/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: thank you for your reply , Mr,Pyramid.I have question also. If I 'd like to see this is working in command of Bitvice, How can I do something?

Comment: yeah.I  have to add this in console.php

Comment: Do you have experience of running crontab in digital ocean server? .Sorry to ask you this question, but if you have , I 'd like to request full help from you

Comment: yeah I have not in digital ocean but on azure and let me tell you crontab will work same on any server whether it is on digital ocean or on azure or on any other server

Comment: if you are getting log after my code that means cron is working fine so first check your logs

Comment: Do you use skype communication tools ?If do , could we connect each other via this for full discussion ?. I had not got log after refer  your code

Comment: nope i am in office I can help you here only btw first check ur logs what you have got?

Comment: Sorry , but There is no changes in log file

Comment: then there is some problem in your cron post your console and job whatever you have here?

Comment: $schedule->command('mail:customer')
                  ->dailyAt('9:00 am');
        $schedule->command('renew:booking')->dailyAt('9:00 am');

Comment: This is schedule code for cron job.Frankly , I am not sure that is right or not.But if I use php artisan renew:booking or mail:customer, that is working as well

Comment: Post it in your question bro

Comment: Could you help me kindly ?

Comment: Yeah will do what problem u r facing

Comment: The problem is that I can not test and see how is working or not.

Comment: Hi, I had just tested "Run php artisan schedule :run " by manually in php storm.Here I saw your log file in laravel.log. If then , how can I run this automatically in digital ocean server, I think your experience will be helpful to me . Thanks you for your help

Comment: ok I will help you tell me where you have this schedule code in project is it in Console.php?

Comment: www_testing is your project name or what?

Comment: please accept the answer to close this question I guess you have got your answer since you haven't answered my last comment too..